# Threads not much faster than no thread version

Tags: java, multithreading

I know there are other questions like that but I'm a beginner and most of the code and questions were quite complicated. Thats why I keep it as simple as possible. I come from an R background but recently I wanted to learn more about Java threads. I run through several tutorial on the topic and most of it boils down to the code I posted below. Note the code is not doing much and I made it quite inefficient so the threads would run a few seconds. 
The main thing to notice is that on my machine the threads run not much faster than the none threaded run. With low values in the for loop in the run method even sometimes slower.  It could be because of my crappy hardware (only two cores), and that with more cores one would see the threads go faster than the non parallel version.  I don't know. But what puzzles me most is that when I look at the System monitor while the program is running in both runs (parallel and non parallel) both cores are used but in the parallel version they run at nearly 100 % and in non parallel both run at 50 - 60 %. Considering that both finish at the same time the parallel version is a lot more inefficient because it uses more computer power for doing the same job not even faster. 
To put it in the nutshell. What am I doing wrong? I thought I wrote the the program not much different than in the Java tutorial. I posted the link below. I run linux ubuntu with the sun version of java.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0160__Thread/0020__Create-Thread.htm

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<PermutateWord> words = new ArrayList<PermutateWord>();
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        for(int i = 0; i < Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();i++){
            words.add(new PermutateWord("Christoph"));
        }
        System.out.println("Run as thread");
        long d = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (PermutateWord w : words) {
            w.start();
        }
        for (PermutateWord w : words) {
            try {
                w.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        for (PermutateWord w : words) {
            System.out.println(w.getWord());
        }
        System.out.println(((double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-d))/1000+"\n");
        System.out.println("No thread");
        d = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (PermutateWord w : words) {
            w.run();
        }
        for (PermutateWord w : words) {
            System.out.println(w.getWord());
        }
        System.out.println(((double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-d))/1000+"\n");
    }
}
class PermutateWord extends Thread {    
    private String word;
    public PermutateWord (String word){
        this.word = word;
    }
    public void run() {
        java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
        for(int i = 0; i <8000000;i++){
            word = swap(word,rand.nextInt(word.length()), rand.nextInt(word.length()));
        }
    }
    private String swap(String word2, int r1, int r2) {
        char[] wordArray = word2.toCharArray();
        char c = wordArray[r1];
        wordArray[r1] = wordArray[r2];
        wordArray[r2] = c;
        return new String(wordArray);
    }
    public String getWord(){
        return word;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Christoph

Comment: Like @akappa said you are doing samething in different threads.It is LIKE saying that you are running multiple instances of your application simultaneously . They are not sharing the tasks but each one is doing sametask .java2s does not have best examples either be mindful of that.

Comment: on my dual core windows machine , it takes 11.966 sec with multiple threads and 18.3 sec with single thread *on average* when run 5 times.

Comment: @Shahzeb See my comment on akappa's answer - this approach to parallelism isn't necessarily useful, but should result in some performance gain.

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster: your reply to my answer assumes something about its "non-threaded" version, which is not included in the question. Maybe the OP should post it, too, but to me it appears as a ridiculous way to parallelize things.

Comment: @Bashkar. I can confirm your results, 10.2 against 14.0 s. And my dual core *is* crappy!

Comment: @akappa It is included. Line 28.

Comment: @Banthar: ooops, I overlooked it. Time to remove my answer...

Comment: @akappa yes , me too and I was arking up for you :)

Comment: Thanks for all you comments. When I run it on my machine I get around 7 seconds for the threaded version and just a small bit more for the non threaded. I should have included that. When I increase the iterations of the for loop in the run method it takes longer(no surprise) but the difference becomes not much more. How I said looking at the system monitor while it run the non threaded version it already uses both cores just not to a hundred percent but finishes almost at the same time on which would make the multi threading part obsolete.

Comment: @Gray I made the program find out how many cores the machine has and instantiate that many threads (or words). I will have a look at executor services and thread pools, thanks.

Comment: Sorry missed that.  If you are limiting the number of threads being created then pools aren't going to help.  You might consider playing with that number however.  Try reducing the number of threads to see if at some point you do get a speed improvement.

Comment: There is no JIT in java, right?

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time is spend allocating and dealocating temporary strings, which has to be synchronized. The work that can be done in parallel is trivial and multiple threads won't give you much gain.

`Math.random()` also has to be synchronized. You will have better results creating local `java.util.Random` for each thread.

```
java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();

public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i <8000000;i++){
        word = swap(word,rand.nextInt(word.length()), rand.nextInt(word.length()));
    }
}
```

But, you should really focus on optimizing `swap` function. I'm not sure, if it does what you want, but I'm sure it's very inefficient. `+` is expensive operation on `String`s. For every `+` JVM has to allocate new `String` which is slow and doesn't work well with multiple threads. If you just want to swap two characters, consider using `char[]` instead of `String`. It should be much easier and much faster.

edit:

```
private String swap(String word2, int r1, int r2) {
    char[] wordArray = word2.toCharArray();
    char c = wordArray[r1];
    wordArray[r1] = wordArray[r2];
    wordArray[r2] = c;
    return new String(wordArray);
}
```

This is much better. However, you are still doing 2 allocations. `toCharArray()` and `new String` both allocate memory. Because rest of your program is very simple, those two allocations take 90% of your execution time.

Comment: That probably sounds very silly for the Java professionals but how would I do that?

Comment: Thanks! Both suggestions improved performance a lot but it did not have any influence on the multi threading. As you said in your answer. Could you explain to me why the work that can be done in parallel is trivial and multiple threads won't give me much gain. Reading all the posts it seems that my understanding of how it works got lost somewhere a long way back.

Comment: This worked very well for me.  Inside of `PermutateWord` you should have a local random `private Random random = new Random();`  Then use `random.nextFloat()` instead of `Math.random()`

Answer (score 0):

I got a lot of mileage out of putting a Thread.sleep(1000) in the join loop.
Empirically, java.util.Random.nextFloat() only bought me 10%.

Even then, both parts ran in 16 seconds on an 8-core machine, suggesting it's 
serializing due to the synchronizations mentioned above. But good, grief, without
the sleep it was running 10x slower.